# Android SDK is not specified in multi-module project

Tags: java, android, angularjs, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I cloned a multi-module project from the `Github` with the following structure,

[image]

It has 5 modules like `android`, `angular-client`, `design-impl`, `hub-spot-email` and lastly, `loan-calc-service`. The moduels `hub-spot-email`, and `loan-calc-service` are the Spring boot app. When I tried to build at the first time, I get the pop-up to set the output path for the project,

[image]

Then, I have set the `hub-spot-email/controller` package as the output path (endpoint). This is the path set for the project,

```
/Users/Somename/IdeaProjects/eclipxgroup-master/hub-spot-email/src/main/java/com/quotecrunchers/email/controller
```

I have tried again to build and I get the error,

```
Error:Android Source Generator: [eclipxgroup-master] Android SDK is not specified
```

I have installed the `Android SDK`. The installation setup is correct as I checked earlier. In the next try, the error doesn't go away. I assume I need to set some path for the android module. I went to the preference section which seems like,

[image]

Also, the Java SDK is properly set though I get the error sings to the left of the files,

[image]

While I have some experience with the java and Spring xxx, I couldn't figure out what I need to do to build the project. Do you have more information what I need to do?

Note

So far I only managed to set the Android SDK for the project.

[image]

Comment: try adding the module for file-->project structure-->app-->from there try adding all the modules projects there by using + button

Comment: Do you have little details? So far I have only been able to set the Android SDK for the project